# TextArea - Resize all textarea in a row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML as below:

```html
    <table border="2">
    
        <tbody><tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Address2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button type="submit" name="delete" value="6">Delete</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <section class="SectionClass">
              <div class="error"></div>
              <div class="inputClass">
                <input id="3da85a67e4914f09b6f673ed730b16a6_12" name="3da85a67e4914f09b6f673ed730b16a6_12" type="text" value="NAME Here">
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
          <td>
            <section class="SectionClass">
              <div class="error"></div>
              <div class="textAreaClass">
                <textarea id="943a646acb564069b5ea6aca27bf6693_13" name="943a646acb564069b5ea6aca27bf6693_13">Address 1
    Address Line 2</textarea>
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
          <td>
            <section class="SectionClass">
              <div class="error"></div>
              <div class="textAreaClass">
                <textarea id="15c3a14f3f4644dda6271cfab7e3b244_14" name="15c3a14f3f4644dda6271cfab7e3b244_14">D
    ffsf
    er</textarea>
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button type="submit" name="delete" value="7">Delete</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <section class="SectionClass">
              <div class="error"></div>
              <div class="inputClass">
                <input id="3da85a67e4914f09b6f673ed730b16a6_15" name="3da85a67e4914f09b6f673ed730b16a6_15" type="text" value="DSRE">
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
          <td>
            <section class="SectionClass">
              <div class="error"></div>
              <div class="textAreaClass">
                <textarea id="943a646acb564069b5ea6aca27bf6693_16" name="943a646acb564069b5ea6aca27bf6693_16">DSS
    fs</textarea>
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
          <td>
            <section class="SectionClass">
              <div class="error"></div>
              <div class="textAreaClass">
                <textarea id="15c3a14f3f4644dda6271cfab7e3b244_17" name="15c3a14f3f4644dda6271cfab7e3b244_17">ewff
    ww
    </textarea>
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
```

I can resize the textarea by clicking resize icon on bottom right. When resizing one textarea I want all other text Areas (in that row) to be resized automatically for Width.

e.g. if I am resizing any column in Address col then it should resize all Address row. Same for Address2

Jquery or CSS solution should be fine for this.

Comment: You could probably listen to the `onresize` event, and adjust the other textareas accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  // variables   
  var x=$('textarea').width();
  var y=$('textarea').height();
  
  $('textarea').mouseup(function () {
    //for resizing the entire textarea in that particular row.
   if ($(this).outerWidth() != x || $(this).outerHeight() != y ) {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('textarea').width($(this).outerWidth());
    $(this).parents('tr').find('textarea').height($(this).outerHeight());
   }
 
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: tx. I need to do for that row

Comment: @user2739418 plz check the above answer(edited according to your need)